# Gives me error while execution "object is not valid"

Tags: sql-server

I want to delete the duplicate records from the table So I used the CTE option but i am getting the below error message. What will be the cause? Am I did anything wrong? Upto select statement it works.

```
with Empcte as (
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID ORDER BY ID) as RowNumber
    from Empgender
)
SELECT *
FROM Empcte

delete from Empcte
where RowNumber > 1
```

---

**Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid object name 'Empcte'.**

Comment: The Select statement uses the CTE and the delete doesn't.  These are two different statements.

Comment: You can refer a CTE only once. You used second time - invalid.

Comment: Your delete statement is a seperate SQL statement, your Common table expression is not valid for both expressions

Comment: @EMUEVIL Thank you for your reply and I solved the issue it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the same CTE for two different statements.   (in this case first a SELECT and then a DELETE)  You either have to re-create the CTE for the DELETE, or use a temp table or table variable instead of a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

A `CTE` is a disposable view. It only persists for a single statement, and then disappears automatically. You can just avoid the `SELECT` statement:

```
WITH Empcte as (
SELECT id
       ,Count() as Rowcount 
FROM Empgender
 Group by id) 
DELETE from Empgender where 
Exists ( select 1 from Empgender as eg where Empcte.id = eg.id and  Empcte.Rowcount >1 and );
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @ Mehrad Eslami Thank you

Comment: if it was your question's answer, would you mark it as answered please?